# Alpine 3.9.4 update busybox 1.30.0

Tags: docker, busybox, alpine-linux

I am using latest stable version of alpine 3.9.4 image. this image comes with busybox -1.29.3-r10. I need to upgrade to busybox `1.30.0`.

`apk upgrade busybox` command not upgrading the package. What is the right steps to upgrade busybox package in Alpine Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BusyBox `1.30.0` is currently available in the `edge` branch, so simply specify `edge/main` as the repository to pull from:

```shell
apk upgrade busybox --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

Alternatively, you could add `edge/main` permanently to your `apk` repo list:

```shell
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories

apk upgrade busybox
```

Or, if you want to pin version 1.30 specifically, you can do so with `apk add`:

```shell
apk add busybox=1.30.1-r1 \
--repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```